# wpf casting of generic items

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a view model that currently looks like below. The TCm type is a domain model type, ie TelephoneNumber. And there are subclassed PcmDetailVms (ie, TelephoneNumberPcmDetailVm). I want to use these properties for a DataGrid that deals the specific TCm (ie, TelephoneNumber).

While it isn't horrible at all to subclass it and do the casting I am wondering if there is any built-in xaml features that would do the casting. Or if it would be more idiomatic to use a converter?

Cheers,
Berryl

## view model

```
public class PcmShellVm<TCm> : ... where TCm : ContactMechanism
{
    public ObservableCollection<PcmDetailVm> DetailVms { get; protected set; }

    public PcmDetailVm SelectedVm {
        get { return _collectionView.CurrentItem as PcmDetailVm; } 
        set { _collectionView.MoveCurrentTo(value); }
    }
}
```

## subclassed vm

```
public class TelecomNumberPcmShellVm : PcmShellVm<TelecomNumber>
{
    ...

    public IEnumerable<TelecomPcmDetailVm> CastedDetailVms { get { return DetailVms.Cast<TelecomPcmDetailVm>(); } }

    public TelecomPcmDetailVm CastedSelectedVm 
    {
        get { return (TelecomPcmDetailVm) SelectedVm; } 
        set { SelectedVm = value; }
    }
}
```

## EDIT

So Andrei had the right answer to the question I did not ask very clearly above. I had incorrectly assumed I needed to cast my items somewhere in xaml, as I would need to do in code.

The binding engine must be using reflection to discover properties by name however, making the cast unnecessary.

Comment: Why you mixed XAMl and type casting? What you want to achieve? Your question looks not clear, please add more details about what are you going to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure I understood the question correctly but I think specific DataTemplates for each type would be an idea.

View :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication18.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:WpfApplication18="clr-namespace:WpfApplication18"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfApplication18:PersonsVM}">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="First name"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Last name"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfApplication18:SpecificPersonsVM}">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LastName}" Header="Last name"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Header="First name"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Age}" Header="Age"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModels :

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication18
{
    public class PersonVM
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class SpecificPersonVM : PersonVM
    {
        public byte Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonsVM
    {
        public ObservableCollection<PersonVM> Items { get; private set; }

        public PersonsVM()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<PersonVM>();
        }
    }

    public class SpecificPersonsVM
    {
        public ObservableCollection<SpecificPersonVM> Items { get; private set; }

        public SpecificPersonsVM()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<SpecificPersonVM>();
        }
    }
}
```

Setupcode (code behind, yeah...)

```
namespace WpfApplication18
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //SetupPersonsVM();
            SetupSpecificPersonsVM();
        }

        private void SetupSpecificPersonsVM()
        {
            var vm = new SpecificPersonsVM();
            vm.Items.Add(new SpecificPersonVM { FirstName = "Johny", LastName = "Bravo", Age = 17 });
            vm.Items.Add(new SpecificPersonVM { FirstName = "Dude", LastName = "Gray", Age = 22 });
            vm.Items.Add(new SpecificPersonVM { FirstName = "Scott", LastName = "Thomas", Age = 34 });
            DataContext = vm;
        }

        private void SetupPersonsVM()
        {
            var vm = new PersonsVM();
            vm.Items.Add(new PersonVM { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Scott" });
            vm.Items.Add(new PersonVM { FirstName = "Matthew", LastName = "Johnson" });
            DataContext = vm;
        }
    }
}
```

You can serve the view different VMs and it will render different things based on this. In my example there is a DataGrid for both VM types but it could have been more different.

Comment: See edited question: I like it a lot but I still need a subclassed VM and casted properties to make it work, yes?

Comment: A subclassed container VM yes, but the properties do not need to be casted as far as I saw and understood.

Comment: See my edited post and you can see where my question was a bit confusing. Like your blog, btw. Cheers

Comment: yes the binding engine uses reflection so no casting will be necessary. PS : My blog sucks but I'm trying to make it suck less... sometimes.